# WooCommerce Tax Apply on Order Total Amount instead of Cart Subtotal?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to apply 25%Tax on Order total amount. In given example it apply on the Subtotal..

Cart Subtotal - 300 ... Shipping - 100 ... Order Total  400 - (Includes 60 VAT)

the 25% of 300 is 60, but I want the result as 25% of 400 is 80.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

- Go to WooCommerce > Settings, open tab Shipping, click on your shipping method and set it to be Taxable.
- Go to tab Tax, select your desired tax class under Shipping Tax Class.
- Open selected tax class settings (click on one of the text links above) and make sure there's a checkbox ticked under "Shipping".

That should be it.